# How to send email with html attachment

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email-attachments

ASP.NET / Mono MVC4 C# application.
html documents needs to be sent by a-mail as attachment.

I tried

```
        using (var message = new MailMessage("from@somebody.com",
            "to@somebody.com",
            "test",
            "<html><head></head><body>Invoice 1></body></html>"
            ))
        {
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            var client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);
        }
```

But html content appears in message body.
How to force html content to appear as e-mail attachment ?

**Update**

I tried Exception answer but document still appears in Windows Mail in message body only.

Message source shows that it contains two parts:

```
----boundary_0_763719bf-538c-4a37-a4fc-e4d26189b18b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

and

```
----boundary_0_763719bf-538c-4a37-a4fc-e4d26189b18b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Both parts have same base64 content.
How to force html to appear as attachment?

Message body can be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send html as attachment then you have to add it in `message` `AlternateView` as shown

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
               ("<html><head></head><body>Invoice 1></body></html>", null, "text/html");

message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

OR

Just create a `txt` or `pdf` or `html` document which you want to send as attachment and do as :-

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf"));
```

OR you can create attachment from memory stream as(sample code you can change as per your requirement) :-

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
writer.Write("<html><head></head><body>Invoice 1></body></html>");
writer.Flush();
writer.Dispose();

System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct 
            = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.html";

ms.Close();
```

Comment: This causes compile error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Mail.AlternateView' to 'string'` at line `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(htmlView));`

Comment: I tried but attachment does not appear and html content  still appears in Windows Mail message body. I  updated question.

Comment: @Andrus..why don't you create a txt or pdf document and send it as attachment??

Comment: Invoices are created in html format from designer. Txt format does not preserve formatting. Converting html to pdf does not in Mono as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469597/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-mono . Since input is already html I'm looking for a way to send html documents as attachments so they can printed, saved and forwarded in untouched form.

Comment: Code is running in Web server and there may be several concurrent requests. I was looking for a solution without creating temporary file in disk for every e-mail. If creating temp file is best solution, how to delete attachment file from disk after it is sent ? Is ot possible to create attachment file in memory as stream from string and using `new Attachment(stream, "file.pdf")` ?

Comment: Your code to create attachment can replaced with single line `Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("<html><head></head><body>Invoice 1></body></html>", "myfile.html");` Is this OK ?

Comment: It worked. Is it OK to use CreateAttachmentFromString instead of code in answer ?

Comment: @Andrus..i have never used CreateAttachmentFromString.. i will just try it and let you know but i have used above code it will work fine.. thanks..

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Mail/Attachment.cs#L114 shows that this method is same as your code. So you can simplify your code a lot.

Comment: @Andrus..yes i have seen your link..what they have done is just made functions like CreateAttachmentFromString but the code inside function is same as above you can just do that way also make it a function and call it where you need it..i have just posted here is simple code you can just modify as the way you need..thanks...

Comment: `AlternateView` is not an attachment. It allows one to send both a plain text email and an html email.