# How to send dymanically generated html as a email attachment in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code to send email but it is failed if I used html attachment.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

System.IO.StreamWriter writer2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
writer2.Write("<html><head></head><body>Invoice 1</body></html>");
writer2.Flush();
writer2.Dispose();

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.To.Add("test@gmail.com");
mm.CC.Add("test2@gmail.com");
mm.From = new MailAddress("test3@gmail.com");
mm.Subject = "नोटिस";
mm.Body = sb.ToString();

System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.html";
mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "rcms.pdf"));
ms.Close();
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469751/how-to-send-email-with-html-attachment

Comment: i used this as a reference but when i am using answer's first part it is sending HTML as a body not as attachment and by using second part error on sending mail.

Comment: ohk i got the answer only one line needed.       var a = System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("<html><head></head><body>'"+sb.ToString()+"'</body></html>", "notices.html");

Answer (score 0):

only one line needed.

var a = System.Net.Mail.Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString("‌​'"+sb.ToString()+"'<‌​/body>", "notices.html");